# replacing \n in a String

Tags: java, string, replaceall

There are several answers to similar questions as mine, but I have tried several of them and they are not working. I must be doing something stupid.

I have

```
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String content = "Test\n another line\n";
if(content.contains("\\n")) {
    content = content.replaceAll("(\\n)", newline);
    System.out.print(content);
}
```

I also tried "\n" and "\\n" in the regex. The content remains unchanged using replaceAll.

Comment: `"(\\\\n){2,}"` Do you know what this regex means?

Comment: *it seems to automatically add a escaping \ prior to each literal "\n"* no, it doesn't. You shouldn't have to replace anything. Post the code using the BufferedReader. Show us an example input. Tell us what you expect the code to do and what it does instead. Also, you don't need any regex to replace a substring by another substring. Use replace().

Comment: you need to understand regular expressions a bit better. search for *regular expression primer* 

 and try :`content = content.replaceAll("(\\n)", newline);`

Comment: @JoSSte He wants to replace the fix `\n` with the line delimiter of the OS. So he doesn't need a Windows version ;P.

Comment: @Tom nicely spotted. I removed the line...

Comment: @JoSSte Like I said, I tried content.replaceAll("(\\n)", newline) and content.replaceAll("(\\\\n)", newline). I did get a result, which made me realise that my problem is not the string but the output of the String to a file. The file output has "0A"\n where there was once a \n so maybe what I need is to get the file output to recognise that \n is a newline character and instead of outputting a literal \n.

Answer (score 3):

Okay facts:

- `\r` is a CR, U+000D
- `\n` is a LF, U+000A

Those characters you can put in a String

```
String s = "line 1.\nline 2.\n";
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

`newline` can be `"\n"` (1 char) or `"\r\n"` (2 chars) or still something else.

If you would read this text, reading first a backslash and then an `n`, it would be in code:

```
String nl = "\\n"; // Two chars, an escaped backslash and a `n`.
String nl = "\\" + 'n'; // Two chars, an escaped backslash and a `n`.
```

If you would want to replace these two chars with a real newline:

```
s = s.replace("\\n", "\n");
s = s.replace("\\n", newline); // Platform dependent
```

Now java regex is still more complex, as it escapes regex letters with a backslash, which in Strings is escaped itself:

You will not need a regex replaceAll/replaceFirst here, but it would go as:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");
```

The pattern containing two backslashes: regex escaping of one backslash.

Answer (score 0):

```
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String content = "Test\\n another line\\n";
if(content.contains("\\n")) {
    content = content.replaceAll("\\\\n", newline);
    System.out.print(content);
}
```

The extra 2 slashes are the escape characters

Comment: Why do you need a group in the regex? `content.replaceAll("\\\\n", newline)` should work as well.

Comment: I was fooled by the Eclipse display of the expression, it introduced the additional '\' for display in Expression watch, the actual string is `"Test\n another line\n"`

Comment: @KDM, My bad. It was a typo

Comment: @hclDave, if it's single \ you can use `\\n`, instead

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this and it works

```
    content.replace("\\n", "\\r\\n")
```

but

```
    content.replaceAll("\\n", "\\r\\n")
```

does not.

So in the end I used

```
    while(content.contains("\\n")) {
        content = content.replace("\\n", newline);
    }
```

And this solves my problem, not elegant, but it works.